# Oracle Associative arrays, how to define?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, associative-array

I am trying to create an associative array in Oracle, when I create a nested table, it works fine:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TRNG_BOOK_AUTHORS_TAB 
AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(500);
```

But when I add the index I get errors:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TRNG_BOOK_AUTHORS_TAB 
AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(500) INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
```

- Error: PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
- Error(2,4): PLS-00355: use of pl/sql table not allowed in this context

What do I have wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a schema type; those can be nested tables or varying arrays (varrays), but not associative arrays.

From the documentation for [the `create type` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/CREATE-TYPE-statement.html):

> A standalone collection type that you create with the `CREATE TYPE` statement differs from a collection type that you define with the keyword `TYPE` in a PL/SQL block or package. For information about the latter, see ["Collection Variable Declaration"](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/collection-variable.html#GUID-89A1863C-65A1-40CF-9392-86E9FDC21BE9).
>
> With the `CREATE TYPE` statement, you can create nested table and `VARRAY` types, but not associative arrays. In a PL/SQL block or package, you can define all three collection types.

Comment: Alex, Thank you for that bit of enlightenment.  I did not realize that they had to be part of a package.  That was the missing link for me, I have it working now, thank you.